# Windows tools to open encrypted DMG files?

Tags: windows, dmg-image

Does anyone know of a tool that will supports encrypted .dmg (OSX disk image) files under Windows?

Comment: first result in google and it's closed. over zealous admins much?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [HFSExplorer](http://hem.bredband.net/catacombae/hfsx.html). I know it can open dmg files, although it's best feature is allowing you to read HFS+ partitions.

Answer (score 3):

[DMGExtractor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/DMGExtractor.shtml) can read encrypted files, according to the developers

Answer (score 1):

**[IsoBuster](http://www.isobuster.com/)** can handle DMG image files

Comment: not sure about encrypted DMG though...

Answer (score 1):

[**7-Zip**](http://7-zip.org/)

Open the dmg and then double-click on the 5.hfsx file.